# Is it possible to update Ubuntu-phone dailys without wiping userdata?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I want to test ubuntu phone and report bugs. But for that I need the daily images and I need to use my phone more or less productively. So it's not satisfying to loose my userdata every day. Can you please help or show me a place where I can find the information?

Regards 
Samuel

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The ubuntu-system image includes an Over The Air (OTA) update mechanism which doesn't delete user data. Go to System Settings and you'll find an "Updates" option.

[image: System Settings]

[image: Downloading update]

[image: Update ready to install]